# Connecting to a MSSQL server behind a firewall

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, firewall

So, I work for a multi-national company and their firewall/security policy is basically "no holes". i.e. anything non-essential is locked out. I can't ssh out/in, telnet out/in, etc. We are trying to build an application to allow for timesheets to be entered offsite, but essentially, the program is going to need to connect to the MSSQL database from anywhere and since I can't get IT to open a firewall port, my options seem severely limited.

The application database also holds a lot of other sensitive internal data, so hosting it externally isn't really a viable option...

At the moment I'm really out of ideas. I was thinking maybe a tunnel or proxy option might be viable, but I'm no expert on networking, so if that is a feasible solution, it would be great if someone could point me to some further info.

Barring that, any other suggestions to get through to the database would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a suggestion: May be you can host a web service that fetches/inserts data into the database from your app.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines. Is it possible to have the web service listen on an in-use port though (like 80 or 25)? Otherwise it won't work...

Comment: As long as there is nothing else on the same IP listening on that port it is fine.  You will probably want to use 443 though and use SSL rather than just HTTP.

Comment: Why would your users outside the firewall need access to the database? Assuming that your application is a web application (if it isn't, it almost certainly should be) then users interact only with the web app, and it connects to the database using an internal connection. So the database is never directly accessed from outside. But having said all that, security isn't easy so you may want to have a consultant or an in-house security team review your design.

Answer (score 0):

RESTful web services over SSL. You can use a X509 client certificate for extra security and/or limit the IP addresses that your service will respond to perhaps.

Second option is a smart client that will work offline, then sync when the users come into the office. [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx).